# Axios, AWS s3 progress bar при загрузке файла

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, axios, amazon-s3

У меня есть сервер на node js,который загружает файлы на aws s3, когда я c фронта на реакте при помощи axios передаю файл, то onUploadProgress у меня возвращает 100% когда файл загрузился именно на node js сервер, как мне сделать на клиенте так, чтобы отображался реальный прогресс с учетом загрузки файла на aws s3.